# Finding Galois groups of polynomials with degree 3

Tags: galois-theory

Determine the Galois groups of the following polynomials with degree 3:

a.) $T^{3} − 2T + 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ und over $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{19})$

b.) $T^{3} − 5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, over $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$ and over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$.

I am currently studying for my exam in algebra and this is one of the preparatory exercises for the exam. However, I don't really understand how to systematically find the Galois groups over those fields. I still lack some understanding when it comes to the Galois theory and I would like to improve that by solving those exercises.

Would anybody help me with the first subexercise a) and then give me some hints so that I can solve b) myself?

Comment: your title needs to be more descriptive. For cubics there's a well known classification via the discriminant for fields of characteristic unequal to $2$

Comment: I changed the title to a more precise description of the exercise. I hope that this title fits the post much better now.

Comment: What happens if you try to use the discriminant? People expect to see some attempts or at least context on what techniques you’ve learned already.

Comment: Finding roots of second polynomial shouldn't be difficult and then you can get the splitting field and the Galois group easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, over $\mathbb Q$. Your polynomial is irreducible since it has no rational roots, and therefore its Galois group must be a transitive subgroup of $S_3$. There are only two such groups: $S_3$ itself and $A_3$. In order to be contained (and hence equal to) $A_3$, it is necessary and sufficient that the discriminant is a rational square. Since the discriminant is negative, it is not a square, and therefore the Galois group is $S_3$.

Now over $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{19})$. If the polynomial had a root $r$ in such field, then it would also have the complex conjugate root. Since $r$ is not rational, then its conjugate differs from $r$, and hence the polynomial has two roots. But then it has three roots, i.e. it is totally split over the base field. This is equivalent to saying that the splitting field of $x^3-2x+2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{19})$. However, since the Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ has order $6$ then the splitting field has degree $6$, while is $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{19})$ is a degree $2$ extension of $\mathbb Q$. Hence, the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{19})$. Now we use the same argument we used over $\mathbb Q$: the discriminant is $-76=(2i\sqrt{19})^2$. Since the discriminant is a square, the Galois group must be $A_3$.